# Disappearing editActionsForRowAtIndexPath actions

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I want to implement `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` to display several options when I left-swipe a cell in my `UITableview`. So I used this code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Obviously, if this returns no, the edit option won't even populate
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //Nothing gets called here if you invoke `tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:` according to Apple docs so just leave this method blank
}

-(NSArray *)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewRowAction *delete = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                    {
                                        // Delete code here
                                    }];

    UITableViewRowAction *changeAmt = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Amt" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                       {
                                           // popover amount change code
                                       }];

    changeAmt.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.022 green:0.541 blue:0.001 alpha:1.00];


    UITableViewRowAction *changeAcct = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Acct" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                        {
                                            // popover account change code
                                        }];

    changeAcct.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.492 blue:0.000 alpha:1.00];

    UITableViewRowAction *viewTrans = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"View" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                        {
                                            // Push to view
                                        }];
    viewTrans.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.002 green:0.342 blue:0.710 alpha:1.00];


    return @[delete,changeAmt,changeAcct,viewTrans]; //array with the buttons delete, changeAmt, changeAcct, viewTrans
}
```

**Yesterday, this code produced this result:**

[image]

**Today, I decided to eliminate the viewTrans action by modifying the editActionsForRowAtIndexPath method like this:**

```
-(NSArray *)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewRowAction *delete = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                    {
                                        // Delete code here
                                    }];

    UITableViewRowAction *changeAmt = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Amt" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                       {
                                           // popover amount change code
                                       }];

    changeAmt.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.022 green:0.541 blue:0.001 alpha:1.00];


    UITableViewRowAction *changeAcct = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Acct" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                        {
                                            // popover account change code
                                        }];

    changeAcct.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.492 blue:0.000 alpha:1.00];

//    UITableViewRowAction *viewTrans = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"View" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
//                                        {
//                                            // Push to view
//                                        }];
//    viewTrans.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.002 green:0.342 blue:0.710 alpha:1.00];


    return @[delete,changeAmt,changeAcct]; //array with the buttons delete, changeAmt, changeAcct, viewTrans
}
```

**This modified code had the effect, somehow, of removing all the actions except the default `Delete` action:**

[image]

So I uncommented the code, and replaced the reference to the `viewTrans` action in the `return` line. **The extra actions do not reappear.**

**This is the only code I modified. Anybody have any idea what I did wrong?**

Answer (score 0):

I had been working on your question and initially, I can't get `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` method called but later I found a little problem and maybe is the same for you, the declaration for the method

```
-(NSArray *)tableview:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is not right, the correct is

```
- (nullable NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

so my method stay like this

```
- (nullable NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewRowAction *delete = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                    {
                                        // Delete code here
                                    }];

    UITableViewRowAction *changeAmt = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Amt" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                       {
                                           // popover amount change code
                                       }];

    changeAmt.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.022 green:0.541 blue:0.001 alpha:1.00];


    UITableViewRowAction *changeAcct = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"Acct" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                        {
                                            // popover account change code
                                        }];

    changeAcct.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.492 blue:0.000 alpha:1.00];

    //UITableViewRowAction *viewTrans = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleDefault title:@"View" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
    //                                   {
                                           // Push to view
    //                                   }];
    //viewTrans.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.002 green:0.342 blue:0.710 alpha:1.00];


    return @[delete,changeAmt,changeAcct]; //array with the buttons delete, changeAmt, changeAcct, viewTrans

}
```

And this is how it looks

[image]

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks, Reinier. I'm pretty new to this so I don't fully understand, but I'll investigate this approach.